# COUNTIF using two conditions while ignoring duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am attempting to create a chart showing the number of BEV/HEV/ICE vehicles bought each year.

I know the formula must have two conditions, but I can't figure out how to get it to ignore duplicates or if it even needs to ignore them?

Here is a photo of the data. Column `K` is the Year, `M` is the vehicle type, and `E` is the unique identifier for each vehicle:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: What you're looking for is a list like this https://i.imgur.com/euJOui3.png? (And what do you mean by "duplicates"? I don't see any rows with the same data for all of the 3 coulmns.)

Comment: Column E is where the duplicates are. And yes a list like that would be perfect

Comment: (Didn't confirm on the output layout idea) But if something is twice in E, but it's a different year or type, how can you not count them? In which year/type do you want to count that one?

Comment: Actually I think you are right, duplicates don't matter since the year will always be different?

Comment: That's what I'd think, though I'm not the one crunching the numbers, and do not know how they're collected to this sheet.

Comment: And sorry about the layout idea, the picture you attached would be perfect.

Comment: The overall goal is just to show how many of each vehicle type exist each year, and then from that I can determine how many of each vehicle type is purchased yearly

Comment: SUMPRODUCT fuction.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you simply want to count everything for the different vehicle types, an easy solution would be the following. I stored the three columns of the data in the range `A1:C22`. The unique vehicle types are stored in `E2:E5` and the year sequence is stored in `F1:W1`, respectively.

Now you can put the following formula in cell `F2` and copy it to all cells, respectively:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$22,$A$1:$A$22,$E2,$B$1:$B$22,F$1)
```

You sum column `C` (sum_range), if the `vehicle_type` matches (condition 1) and the `year` matches (condition 2), accordinlgy.

The final output looks as follows:

[image: output]

The data used is the following (might need to be adjusted according to your concrete column that captures the number of vehicles bought):

| vehicle_type | replacement | purchase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HEV | 2026 | 24227 |
| HEV | 2033 | 26045 |
| PHEV | 2040 | 22149 |
| ICE | 2023 | 18159 |
| ICE | 2029 | 25247 |
| ICE | 2036 | 28432 |
| HEV | 2026 | 24227 |
| HEV | 2033 | 26045 |
| PHEV | 2040 | 22149 |
| BEV | 2029 | 35281 |
| BEV | 2036 | 27247 |
| ICE | 2026 | 26261 |
| ICE | 2033 | 28496 |
| ICE | 2040 | 32732 |
| ICE | 2023 | 28781 |
| ICE | 2029 | 34844 |
| ICE | 2036 | 39240 |
| ICE | 2029 | 32323 |
| ICE | 2036 | 32454 |
| ICE | 2029 | 32323 |
| ICE | 2036 | 32454 |

Comment: Instead of summing could I just use countif in that formula? I just need to know the quantity of each vehicle type per year

Comment: @Davdgup Yes, in that case you can simply use `=COUNTIFS()`, and remove the sum_range. The updated formula in cell `F2` is as follows: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$22,$E2,$B$1:$B$22,F$1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIFS` for this, as follows.

First create the column headers with the types and first row with the years (something like below, I put the type in the columns and the years in the rows since the years are more so it's neater this way):
[image]

Then in the cell at the intersection of BEV:2026 (`B2` in the example) enter the following (where `B$1` is the cell with *BEV* and `$A2` is the cell with *2026*):

```
=COUNTIFS($M:$M,B$1,$K:$K,$A2)
```

Fill drag across to all types, then (having all the results of the first year selected) fill drag down to all years.

---

If you want the column headers (type) and first row (years) auto-generated based on what you have in your data (and you don't need rows for years that have no sales), then you can use the following:

- In `A2` use: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(K:K,K:K<>""))`
- In `B1` use: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(M:M,M:M<>"")))`

Then in `B2` use this (and drag across and down a bunch of columns/rows, on the range where there won't be anything in the year or type it will result in blank):

```
=IF(OR(B$1="",$A2=""),"",COUNTIFS($M:$M,B$1,$K:$K,$A2))
```